# How can we get total number of files & directory count from google drive account using API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want total file & directory count from google drive account using google drive python SDK.

Comment: I suggest to visit the [documentation on how to work with folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder), and from there, you will be redirected to the [Files reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files).

Comment: This links gives information related to managing folder. Could you please let me know how can I get total files count?